# print the value of a variable from javascript to html

Tags: javascript, html, json

How can print the value of variable count in ministries().For example i have 54 object.so it will show ministries(54).How can i print 54(value of count) in ministries.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Data Retrieve</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        #p1    {background-color: violet;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <table id="info_table" class="table">
        <tr>
          <td><p align="center"><b>Ministry</b></p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="p1">  
          <td><p align="center"><b>Total ministries()</b></p></td>
        </tr>
      </table>      
    </div> 
  </div>
</body>
</html>  
<script>
    $.getJSON("http://localhost/directory/ministri.json",function(obj){
        var info ='';
        //alert(obj.data.length);
        var count = obj.data.length;
        $.each(obj.data,function(key,value){

            info += '<tr>';
            info +='<td><a href="http://localhost/directory/show.php?id='+value.id+'" style="text-decoration:none">'+value.sitename_bn+'<span style="float: right"> > </span>'+ '</a></td>';
            info += '</tr>';

        });

           $('#info_table').append(info);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please post your code in the question instead of a picture of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really simple. Just target your element `#p1` and replace its HTML with the value you got.

```
$('#p1 td').html("<p><b>Total ministries(" + count + ")</b></p>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your table structure to

```
<table id="info_table" class="table">
    <thead>
         <tr>
      <td><p align="center"><b>Ministry</b></p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="p1">  
      <td><p align="center"><b>Total ministries()</b></p></td>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

and then change jQuery code to

```
$('#info_table > tbody').append(info);
```